# Odd behavior when creating and cancelling a thread in close succession

Tags: pthreads

I'm using g++ version 4.4.3 (`Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5`) and libpthread v. 2-11-1. The following code simply creates a thread running `Foo()`, and immediately cancels it:

```
void* Foo(void*){
   printf("Foo\n");
   /* wait 1 second, e.g. using nanosleep() */

   return NULL;
}

int main(){
   pthread_t thread;

   int res_create, res_cancel;
   printf("creating thread\n);
   res_create = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Foo, NULL);
   res_cancel = pthread_cancel(thread);
   printf("cancelled thread\n);
   printf("create: %d, cancel: %d\n", res_create, res_cancel);

   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
creating thread
Foo
Foo
cancelled thread
create: 0, cancel: 0
```

Why the second `Foo` output? Am I abusing the pthread API by calling `pthread_cancel` right after `pthread_create`? If so, how can I know when it's safe to touch the thread? If I so much as stick a printf() between the two, I don't have this problem.

Comment: Tried on MacOS 10.6.8 and it works...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this on a slightly newer Ubuntu. Sometimes I get one `Foo` and sometimes none. I had to fix a few things to get your code to compile (missing headers, missing call to some sleep function implied by a comment and string literals not closed), which indicate you did not paste the actual code which reproduced the problem.

If the problem is indeed real, it might indicate some thread cancellation problem in glibc's IO library. It looks a lot like two threads doing a `flush(stdout)` on the same buffer contents. Now that should never happen normally because the IO library is thread safe. But what if there is some cancellation scenario like: the thread has the mutex on `stdout`, and has just done a flush, but has not updated the buffer yet to clear the output. Then it is canceled before it can do that, and the  main thread flushes the same data again.